# Show that $\bar{x}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's think about the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-1)$. I can show $\overline{x}$ is not prime element. It is because  $\overline{x^3}\in (\bar{x})$ and $\overline{x^3}=\overline{y^2-1}=(\overline{y-1})(\overline{y+1})$( of corse I have to show $\overline{y+1},\overline{y-1}\notin (\bar{x})$, but I omit here). But why is $\bar{x}$ irreducible element? Although similar questions were asked, I found no method which can be applied to this question. Please give me some advice.

Comment: by the definition of quotient and the degree of polynomial.

Comment: You ask in title to show that $\bar x$ is irreducible, and in the body ask "why is $\bar x$ not irreducible element?" Which are you actually asserting?

Comment: Sorry. I edited.

Comment: @Sky: I wrote $\bar{x}=\bar{f}(x,y)\bar{g}(x,y)$ mod $(y^2-x^3-1)$. This means there is $h(x,y)$ such that $x+h(x,y)(y^2-x^3-1)=f(x,y)g(x,y)$. Can I get information about the degree?

Comment: @masutarou you can consider one variable.

Comment: @Sky Ok. I consider variable "$y$". Then  $f(x,y)=ya(x)+b(x),g(x,y)=yc(x)+d(x)$. The condition changed to "$x+h(x,y)(y^2-x^3-1)=y^2a(x)c(x)+y(a(x)d(x)+b(x)c(x))+b(x)d(x)$. Paying attention to the degree of $y$, $h(x,y)$ is a polynomial of only $x$, i.e. $h(x,y)=h(x)$.

Comment: @Sky Arranging on $y$, I got $a(x)d(x)+b(x)c(x)=0$ and $b(x)d(x)=x+a(x)c(x)(-x^3-1)$. Considering the degree of $x$. $\cdots$ I have a contradiction. This is a luck of my thinking. Thank you.

Comment: @masutarou you are welcome